# Find Samba/CIFS version on fresh install

Tags: samba, cifs, smb

I have a fresh installation of Ubuntu (several versions) and I want to discover which version of Samba/CIFS it is using to mount drives.  I have installed nothing since the OS installation (except gksu and cifs-utils) and I have not yet run updates.  It is mounting a couple of CIFS shares via fstab as expected.  How do I discover what version the OS is using to establish these mounts?

For those interested, the problem/bug is as follows.

Files and folders which include a : or a ? in their titles are not accessed from certain versions of Ubuntu.  The server is correctly serving the files because up until at least Ubu 12.04.5 the files/folders were accessible.  By 14.04.5 any file or folder with these characters (and perhaps others considered dangerous by Windows) act thus:  folders display and show contents = 0 but cannot be accessed; files display but throw an error when clicked upon.  I am seeking the exact point of breakage.

Comment: That is not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Using apt-cache policy cifs-utils I get the version of cifs-utils.  If there is another component involved, please let me know.  Otherwise I will pursue this line for filing a bug report.

Comment: It does not make sense to file a bug report for an unsupported version. 15.10 is End of Live!

Comment: I am trying to locate the point of change.  This problem exists in 16.04 and I'm seeking the cutoff.

Comment: I see, it might be a good idea to edit the question and add a description of the problem you experience in 16.04. Probably someone here has a solution.